# Apple rejection for using HealthKit

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, healthkit

I am using HealthKit in my app to read users daily steps data and for that I enable HealthKit in my app.

I have uploaded it to iTunes for approval and it has been rejected for the following reason:

> Your app uses the HealthKit or CareKit APIs but does not indicate
>   integration with the Health app in your app description and clearly
>   identify the HealthKit and CareKit functionality in your app's user
>   interface.

I have provided below mentioned description of HealthKit while approval.

> WayOL app uses the Apple health app to track your steps, activity and
>   sleep data. Daily steps and sleep data show up on the timeline screen.

Can anyone guide me what am i suppose to do?

Comment: you need to give some information about healthkit in app description, why you are using it, where you using this data in your app.

Comment: Does your app description say anything like "reads users daily steps data from HealthKit?" The reason sounds pretty straightforward. What's your app description say? (Not that SO can help you much here; "why did Apple reject my app" is not a technical question SO can answer. Often Apple can't answer it.)

Comment: i have already given sufficient description of same then also i am facing this issue again and again.

Comment: I have updated the question with application's description @RobNapier

Comment: i have already mentioned it application's description part @Yitzchak

Comment: you need to update description. Find out some fitness apps on itunes that use healthkit from there you can get an idea .e.g. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/weight-tracker-for-healthkit/id936275753?mt=8

Comment: How to show UI? @Yitzchak

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I'm having the same problem with HealthKit for my app. My app uses HealthKit to track steps. We have stated in both app description and in-app user interface that the tracking function uses HealthKit and still it got rejected. The review teams kept asking to update UI, but the statement is already in there. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LPxpY6OfADWvXcUx-z0WBHVZ_8fzhw_W   https://drive.google.com/open?id=14C4UrL5r3eRtipVgnwScLiKeVq5FcUTW @Aman.Samghani

Comment: similar problem. How to show it in the UI? Is there an example?